# hazelcast 3.2 slow when deployed using TomEE 1.6.0

Tags: hazelcast, apache-tomee

I want to upgrade from TomEE 1.5.1 to TomEE 1.6.0.
I have some hazelcast maps that are populated during server startup.
When deployed on TomEE 1.5.1 works fast (less than a second to populate and index 2k items, including some processing in between).
When deploying the exact same WARs to TomEE 1.6.0 the same tasks takes ~4 seconds.

To complete the picture, when running unit-test with openejb.home pointing to openejb 4.6.0 - it runs perfectly well.

Any ideas?

**===== edit =====**
I realized that this is a bit in the air.
Here's a link to a simple war that puts 50000 items to the map.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Xw6Xt1YU4bVy16NE9Xc295LTA/edit?usp=sharing

I deployed it in apache-tomee-plus-1.5.1 and in apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.6.0. The time was ~2.5 sec and ~10 sec, respectfully.
There are emphasized output in the tomee log to indicate the time.
Sources are included.
I hope it helps in understanding and solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

basically you are stucked in hazelcast:

```
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocation.java:721)
    - locked <0x00000007c58b50c0> (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:695)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:674)
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:239)
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.putInternal(MapProxySupport.java:200)
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:57)
```

You can take some thread stack in both instances to compare but TomEE didn't change enough to justify alone such a difference.

Do you use the exact same network config?

Comment: Yes.I have 2 folders - one for TomEE 1.5.1 and one for 1.6.0. I deployed the same war and got the time differences. 
BTW - I don't get any exceptions on (both) TomEE startup. What's the difference in mine/yours deployments?
No configuration diff.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any exception neither. Just got a thread dump when started to see if tomee was the bottlenexk or not. Since the time is spent in hazelcast TomEE shouldn't be the cause of it so you need to compare both instances.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by editing the objects that hazelcast serialize.
For TomEE 1.5.1, those objects were implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface and the performance difference occured.
I changed it to `com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializable` and things run faster and are consistent in both servers.
So, although my problem was solved, I still don't understand the behavior differences.

Answer (score 0):

it can be classloading difference, tomee 1.6 tolerate a bit more classes from the webapp by default. Playing with openejb.classloader.forced-skip=package1,package2,... to exclude common classes between webapp and tomee/lib can make it faster